# Am I creating a memory leak and how to fix it

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, memory-leaks, free

I am asking because I am creating an initialArray, but then I point it to a new array without freeing the initially allocated space.
I tried to do `free(initialArray)` before pointing it to my newArray, so I will free up the previously used array - it'll be like:

```
free(initialArray);
initialArray = newArray;
```

but I am getting a core dump. any help?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ENLARGE_SIZE(x, y) x += y
#define SIZE_INCREMENT 10

int *get_set();

int main() {
    int i = 0;
    int *set = get_set();
    printf("Array elements:\n");
    while (*(set + i) != '\0') {
        printf("%d,%d\n", *(set + i), i);
        i++;
    }
    free(set);
    return 1;
}

int *get_set() {
    int *initialArray = malloc(sizeof(int) * SIZE_INCREMENT);
    int arraySize = 5;
    int arrayElementCount = 0;
    int scannedInt;
    int i = 0;
    while (scanf("%d", &scannedInt) != EOF) {
        printf("Scanned %d\n", scannedInt);
        arrayElementCount++;
        if (arraySize == arrayElementCount) {
            int *newArray = realloc(initialArray, sizeof(int) * (ENLARGE_SIZE(arraySize, SIZE_INCREMENT)));
            initialArray = newArray;
            arraySize += SIZE_INCREMENT;
        }
        *(initialArray + i) = scannedInt;
        i++;
    }
    return initialArray;
}
```

Comment: You add `SIZE_INCREMENT` to `arraySize` twice, once in the `ENLARGE_SIZE` macro and once in a separate statement.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `realloc` to extend the array:

- if `realloc` is successful, the previous object pointed to by `initialArray` has been freed, so you can just store the newly allocated object to `initialArray` directly as posted.
- if `realloc` failed, `newArray` is `NULL` and the original object is still allocated and accessible via `initialArray`.  You can free it if you decide to abort the function.

Also note these remarks:

- the syntax `*(set + i)` is less readable than the equivalent array expression `set[i]`.  Prefer the latter unless you are instructed to only use the former.
- `while (scanf("%d", &scannedInt) != EOF)` is incorrect. You should check for successful conversion with:

  ```
  while (scanf("%d", &scannedInt) == 1)
  ```
- `get_set()` should set a `0` value at the end of the allocated array.  It might be a good idea to also return the number of elements via a pointer.
- your handling of the array size in `get_set` is confusing.  Simplify it this way:

```
#define SIZE_INCREMENT 10

int *get_set(void) {
    int arraySize = SIZE_INCREMENT;
    int arrayElementCount = 0;
    int *array = malloc(sizeof(*array) * arraySize);
    int scannedInt;

    if (!array) {
        fprintf(stderr, "allocation error\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    while (scanf("%d", &scannedInt) == 1) {
        printf("Scanned %d\n", scannedInt);
        if (arrayElementCount + 2 > arraySize) {
            int *newArray = realloc(array, sizeof(*newArray) * (arraySize + SIZE_INCREMENT));
            if (!newArray) {
                fprintf(stderr, "allocation error\n");
                free(array);
                return NULL;
            }
            array = newArray;
            arraySize += SIZE_INCREMENT;
        }
        array[arrayElementCount++] = scannedInt;
    }
    array[arrayElementCount] = 0;
    return array;
}
```

Comment: @Fe2O3: good point. Answer amended.